# MplayerCtrl is giving an error from source code.

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Im trying to get mplayerctrl set up on my machine but when I got to run the program im getting the following error.

```
PS C:\Users\csell\Desktop\CIS457_Semester_Project-master> python VideoPlayer.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "VideoPlayer.py", line 5, in <module>
    import MplayerCtrl as mpc
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\MplayerCtrl.py", line 906
    except Exception, e:
```

Im installing it using pip running these commands:

```
pip install wxPython
pip install MplayerCtrl
```

I am currently running python 3.7.1. Any help on why this error is occurring or how I can fix it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your lib seems to be Python 2 only since it has Python 2 syntax.

Comment: [Python2-only](https://bitbucket.org/dav1d/mplayerctrl/src/b712bf2559da97274ae1845178933dd301098831/setup.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#setup.py-25).